# How to multisort list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

list have structure:

```
test = [{"title": title, "ratio": ratio, "delta": begin - now()}]
```

Need to sort by ratio ( max->min) and after sort by delta (min->max) ) ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use those two values of those two keys as representative of the current dictionary during the sorting's comparison.

```
sorted(test, key=lambda x: (-x['ratio'], x['delta']))
```

will sort them based on `ratio`'s descending order first and if the values are equal, then `delta`'s ascending order.

---

Here, we negate the value of `d['ratio']`, because by default, `sorted` does sort in ascending order. As we want the largest value of `ratio` to be at the beginning, we negate the value so that the biggest `ratio` will be treated as the smallest `ratio`. (For example out of 1, 10, and 100, after negating the values, -100 will be the smallest).

We want Python to use both the `ratio` and `delta`. So, we return the values of them in a tuple. When Python compares two dictionaries, it calls the `key` function with the dictionary objects as parameters and get two tuples and they will be compared to determine the smaller of the two. First, it compares the first elements of the tuples, if they are same, then the second elements will be compared.

Comment: should the `d` be an `x`?

Answer (score 3):

As simple as:

```
from operator import itemgetter

>>> result = sorted(test, key=itemgetter('-ratio'))
>>> result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter('delta'))
```